# Duplicate Set of Code and Controls independently (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

Help Please  - vb.net.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have a set of controls and I would like to duplicate them 25 times along with the coding, however, I want them all to work independently from each other... I don't know if what I want is possible but please advise me :D 
So far I have copied and pasted the controls 25 times and I am busy renaming allllll the buttons and labels etc... and it's taking forever!

Comment: You have to create new controls (associate new properties, events, etc.) at runtime (unless the number of repeated controls is too big and the program has to be loaded very fast -> unlikely). This is more or less straightforward by relying on a loop making the names depending upon the counter. Simple example: (inside the loop) `count = count + 1  Dim button As Button = New Button button.Name = "name" + count`; you can set a group of common properties for each group of buttons (e.g., location, events, etc.) what would increase a bit the complexity of the loop.

Comment: No problem. But if you wait a bit perhaps someone writes an answer with a sample code which might even be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would create a UserControl. To do so:

1. right click on your solution and Add/User Control
2. Put your Buttons, Labels and whatnot in the Control Designer
3. Compile your project.

You should now be able to see your very own control in the Toolbox. Put one or two (or how many you like) on your form.

The next thing you should think about is: What is always identical in each OurOwnControl-Instance and what is different?

From the screenshot above I see, that there is a label "Drive 1". Right now each OurOwnControl-Instance is identical, including the "DriverLabel". To change this add the following to your UserControl:

```
Public Property DriveLabelText() As String
    Get
        Return lblDriver.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        lblDriver.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Compile your project. Now you should be able to change the DriverLabel Property on the controls sitting on your Form.

The next thing you might need is to do different things (on the Form), when "things" a happening inside the UserControl. Let's say you need to know when Start-Button is clicked. If always the same thing is happening, just put the Code in the StartButton_Click Event Handler inside the UserControl. But what if you want to different things, depending on the driver? Put the following inside the UserControl:

```
Public Event StartButtonClicked As EventHandler

Private Sub StartButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    RaiseEvent StartButtonClicked(Me, New EventArgs())
End Sub
```

Compile your project. You should now be able to subscribe the StartButtonClicked Event inside your Form.

I hope this is detailed enough :)

**Q: How would I retrieve the value of a Numeric up/down from form1 and use that in my new usercontrol?**

There are (at least) two possibilities:

1) The right way: You shouldn't. In an ideal world, the UserControl should know nothing about the world around it. Insteead the Form should set the desired value from the outside. You could do this with a Property as described above.

The reason for this is: What would happend if you decide that your new ShinyControl could be use full in a totally different Project? The Form would most likely be different.

2) The lazy way:

```
Dim myForm As Form1 = Me.FindForm()
Dim foo = myForm.UpDownControl1.Value
```

Comment: OMG you brilliant person you! :D Thank you so much, nice and simple even for me to understand! :D:D:D:D

Comment: Glad that I could helped :)

Comment: How would I retrieve the value of a Numeric up/down from form1 and use that in my new usercontrol :D?

Comment: You are amazing thank you again :D I will try the property method but may result in using the lazy method because it's simplier xD